# get before last value bufferreader socket

Tags: java, sockets

i have probleme i want to get before last element in bufferreader socket

```
message = bufferedReader.readLine()
```

i want to get this output

exemple bufferreader messages contains: [Ajay, Becky, Chaitanya, Dimple, Rock]
before Last element is:
dimple

Answer (score 2):

```
 if (al != null && al.size()>=2) {
    System.out.println("Last element is:");
    System.out.println(al.get(al.size()-2));
 }
```

because `list.size()-1` is the last element. 
So `list.size()-2` is the previous last element.

In a array or a collection, the index begins to `0`, so the last element is size of the `array/collection -1`.

---

For your second question :

> I have problems in socket bufferreader
>
> i want to get last before message
>
> message = bufferedReader.readLine()

You don't read message but line here. If you want to identify the before last line, your could do it by supposing that you have at least 2 elements to read.

```
String[] lastTwoElements= new String[2];
String currentLine;
            while ((currentLine=br.readLine()) != null) {
                String oldLastElement = lastTwoElements[1]; 
                lastTwoElements[1] = currentLine;
                lastTwoElements[0] = oldLastElement;
            }
```

`lastTwoElements[0]` is the previous last read line.
`lastTwoElements[1]` is last read line.

Comment: Its a zero based index so if size is 10 the first element is at position 0 last element is at position 10 -1 or 9 so the element before last is at 10 -2 so index 8.

Comment: xception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
 at java.util.ArrayList.elementData(ArrayList.java:418)
 at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:431)
 at ThreadSocket.run(ThreadSocket.java:44)

Comment: With this modification, it should not be possible. Just replace your `if` statement by the `if` statement I posted

Comment: In your code, you don't refer to `BufferedReader`. I just proposed you an idea. I edited the code. If it doesn't address your problem, you can edit your question as Tom suggests or close this question and open a new question.

Comment: Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null

Answer (score 0):

```
if (al != null && !al.isEmpty()) {
   System.out.print("ArrayList contains: ");
   for(int i =0; i <a1.size(); i++){
      System.out.print(a.get(i) + ", ");
   }
   System.out.println("\nbefore Last element is: "+a1.get(a1.siz2() - 2));
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)